# django grouping query on multiple tables with foreign keys

Tags: django

I'm having a hard time figuring out a query to do multiple groups in django:
Here is my model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.charField(max_length=15)

class Release(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

class Analysis(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    release = models.ForeignKey(Release, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

What I want to do is get all analyses of profile 1&2 which have the latest release for that profile.
Example:

```
profile id | analysis_id   | release_id
    1      |     1         |   1
    1      |     2         |   1
    1      |    *3*        |   2
    1      |    *4*        |   2
    2      |    *5*        |   1
    2      |    *6*        |   1
```

Note that I am not just after the greatest release id, but the greatest release id for that profile.

I want to to get analysis ids 3,4,5,6.
Here is my attempt which does not give me what I want:

```
print Analysis.objects.filter(profile__id__in=[1, 2]).annotate(rid=Max('release__id')).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

It returns all the ids.
Any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

[Use a reference filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model) after the annotation to refer back to the maximum value.

```
from django.db.models import F
print Analysis.objects.filter(profile__id__in=[1, 2]
   ).annotate(rid=Max('release__id')
   ).filter(release__id=F('rid') 
   ).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

---

Note, I've used these before to great effect, but I haven't fully tested it with your model <sup>*</sup>.

<sup><sub>* Your millage may vary. Consult a doctor if database queries last longer than 4 hours.</sub></sup>

Comment: This suggestion makes sense; however, it still is outputing all the ids.